# How to bring 3D object into 3D application?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d, 3d-analyst, modelling, arcglobe

I'm doing some GIS as part of my college course and have just started to do some 3D modelling, I'm really a GIS novice, The module is short (only 5 lectures) My lecturer has said that it is possible to bring in an object such as a tree or wind turbine and place it on the 3D model, (problem is he doesn't know how to do it) can anybody on here help. I don't need it for exam or any thing, but I am doing a few maps for my final year project and would like to do a 3D model.

Answer (score 2):

You can import the models from sketch up or a cad file that is designed in 3d. The key for models in ArcGIS is multi patch. If going from sketchup export to kml. What you're after is the colada (.dae) file. A kml can be renamed to .zip and you will find the dae inside. If importing from cad just make sure the file has 3d units, and dwg will work fine. ArcGIS will even open that directly.

Make sure you have 3D analyst for ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **[Google SketchUp to ArcGIS tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUSTM5_PPOk)** available on **YouTube** which may help you do this in **ArcScene** if using ArcGlobe is not a mandatory requirement.